# Implementing callback (for C library) as pure virtual in C++ abstract class

Tags: c++, c, callback, polymorphism

I ran into a problem when using a C audio library *(PortAudio built with ASIO SDK, but this isn't really relevant to this question; the technical details would only hinder me asking the question)*.

Simply put, a certain C function from that library requires me to give it a callback function that returns a certain value and accepts certain parameters; for the sake of clarity, let's say the callback should look like this:

```
int callback(int arg)
```

and the call to the library function looks like this:

```
theCLibraryFuntion(foo, bar, callback);
```

Using the library like this (i. e. in the procedural C-style way) works fine, but I would like to wrap the library functionalities that are relevant to me in nicely structured C++ classes. The project I need the library for is the biggest I've worked on so far, so OO-design is a must for me. **I want to create an abstract class in C++ that provides a pure virtual function for derived classes to implement, and then have that implementation be used for the callback by a class that knows about the library.** In other words, I need actual polymorphism rather than nasty function pointer cruft.

I haven't been able to write such classes so far. The compiler won't allow me to pass nonstatic member functions of any class as callback to the C library function. I understand why, but I would like to know about some workaround for this. As long as that workaround, if it exists, gives me polymorphic behaviour for the front-end classes, I don't care how evil the back-end code becomes. If no such workaround exists, so be it. I understand quite well how C works in the background, but I know little about the technicalities of the OO-features in C++ so I'm going to assume there is a way.

Thanks in advance!

*Note: a workaround that would add considerable overhead is likely to be worthless to me. I'm forced to use this C portaudio library because it's the only API that gives me the extremely low latency for audio streaming my project requires, so drastically increasing overhead isn't really an option.*

Comment: Callbacks without `void*` parameters. Aaaaaah...

Comment: They seem to have detailed documentation online. Could you please specify which callback you need to implement?

Comment: It's just a simplified example, the actual callback has more than one void* parameter, I assure you.
@sharptooth: It's the standard stream callback. But I just need a workaround for callbacks in general... if that makes sense.

Comment: @DiscobarMolokai: Does it have "void* userData"?

Comment: @sharptooth: yes, it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is oversimplified. In real world both the "library function" and the callback will have a `void*` "user data" parameter. You can pass a pointer to your class instance into "user data" of the "library function" and it will be forwarded into the callback where you can use that pointer to access the object.

```
class CallbackImplBase {
public:
   virtual void CallbackImpl() = 0;
   static void CallbackToPass( void* userData )
   {
       static_cast<CallbackImplBase*>(userData)->CallbackImpl();           
   }
};

class ActualCallbackImpl : public CallbackImplBase {
     void CallbackImpl() { //implemented here }
};

ActualCallbackImpl callback;
callLibraryFunction( params,
   &CallbackImplBase::CallbackToPass, static_cast<CallbackImplBase*>( &callback ) );
```

Note the `static_cast` near the last parameter of the "library function" call. You won't need it unless you have multiple inheritance, it's still there anyway.

Comment: An elegant solution! I think this will do just fine. Many thanks!

Comment: I should add that I just tried using this in my project, and it does actually work in the context I need it to work. I didn't expect it to be this simple, though... ;)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the callbacks in PortAudio, such as [this one](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/portaudio_8h.html#ab2530ee0cb756c67726f9074d3482ef2), take a `void*` argument for passing user data to them. You can use this to call member functions by passing a class pointer as user data, and writing a small static or non-member function to register as the C-compatible callback. For example:

```
// C library function
typedef void (*c_library_callback)(void * user_data);
void c_library_start_stuff(c_library_callback, void * user_data);

// C++ class using it
class audio_thing {
public:
    virtual ~audio_thing() {} // Better have one of these in an abstract class

    void start_stuff() {
        c_library_start_stuff(&audio_thing::static_callback, this);
    }
private:
    // C-compatible callback forwards to the implementation
    static void static_callback(void * thing) {
        static_cast<audio_thing*>(thing)->callback();
    }

    // Derived classes implement the callback behaviour
    virtual void callback() = 0;
};
```

Comment: Make it virtual void callback() = 0 and it is an abstract class

Comment: @DieterLücking: Oh yes, I didn't notice that requirement.