# passing a pointer to a virtual member function as argument to an ordinary C function

Tags: c++

I need some help from you, because I have no idea how to achieve the following (and it might be not possible at all) :

suppose I have a class hierarchy like

```
class Base
{
public :
    .....
    virtual int fcn(unsigned, const double *, void *,unsigned, double)=0;
    ....
};

class Derived_1:public Base
{
public :
    .....
    int fcn(unsigned, const double *, void *,unsigned, double);
    ....
};

class Derived_2:public Base 
{
public :
    .....
    int fcn(unsigned, const double *, void *,unsigned, double);
    ....
};
```

I need to to integrate the member function fcn and I would like to use a numerical integration package (by S.G. Johnson, look at http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Cubature) which consists (beside others) in a routine defined as :

```
int h_cubature(unsigned fdim, integrand f, etc ..);
```

where f represents a pointer to the function to be integrated, and  "integrand" is a typedef :

```
typedef int (*integrand) (unsigned, const double *, void *,unsigned, double);
```

What I'm trying to do is passing to h_cubature a pointer to member function fcn, which I want to integrate (moreover by a polymorphic mechanism, i.e. given a pointer of Base class type) That is, something like

```
int main()
    {
    Base* b;
    Derived_1 d1;
    b=&d1;
    hcubature(2, b->fcn, ........);  //<---I don't know how to pass b->fcn
    ....
```

Passing b->fcn to h_cubature as above, causes GNU GCC compiler to issue the error

```
cannot convert 'Base::fcn' from type 'int (Base::)(unsigned int, const double *, void*, unsigned int, double*)' to type 'integrand {aka int (*)(unsigned int,const double*, void*, unsigned int, double*)}'|
```

Whatever else I tried, it failed. The problem I see is that, even if both integrand and fcn have both same signature and the same return type, b->fcn is a virtual member function while integrand is a C-type ordinary function.

Can somebody tell me how to pass the b->fcn pointer to h_cubature (or possibly tell me that it is not possible)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That C `integrand` function looks like a callback function with `void*` parameter that could store the address to the object. This answer should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/21480797/57428

Comment: A pointer to a member function is *not* the same as a pointer to a non-member function, you can't use those interchangeably. How would, for example, the C function know which object to call the member function on?

Comment: It's not possible without passing an actual object that can be used to call that function. This won't be possible for plain c.

Comment: You can pass a pointer to a plain function (or a static member function). That function would have to create or obtain otherwise an object and call that object's member function, virtual or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass a C++ (non-static) *member function* to a C function pointer (intuitively, because these member functions have `this` as an *implicit* formal argument).

But probably, the third formal of `integrand` can be an arbitrary pointer. So pass the object's address thru it, and use as the `integrand` some glue `extern "C"` or `static` function :

```
static int my_integrand (unsigned i, const double *t, void *data, 
                         unsigned j, double x)
{
   Base* b = static_cast<Base*>data;
   assert (b != nullptr);
   return b->fcn(i,t,data,j,x);
}
```

I guess that you don't need to pass `data` to `b->fcn` (so you could correct its signature in your `Base`, `Derived1`, `Derived2` classes...)

Later use `hcubature(fdim, my_integrand, &d1,`......

Comment: This is my problem too (using hcubature) and the third argument ("void *data") is already being used to pass data - as a pointer to an array of doubles. Can it be used to pass the object's address as well?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass pointer to class member function as argument expecting pointer to function. This is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass this as a regular C function nor can you use a lambda or bind.

If you are in control of the `void *` parameter of the function, i.e. it is a "magic cookie" that you provide, you can use that to actually contain a `Base *` pointer then cast it and call your virtual function from it.

```
class Base
{
  public:
    virtual int fcn(unsigned, const double *,unsigned, double)=0; // no void * param
};

int BaseFcn( unsigned u1, const double * pd, void * pv unsigned u2, double d )
{
    Base * base = static_cast< Base * >( pv );
    return base->fnc( u1, pd, u2, d );
}
```

If that is not the case and you just want to use a base class to determine what function you are going to pass without passing in a "this", you can have a virtual function to return a function.

```
class Base
{
 public:
    virtual integrand fcn() const = 0;
};
```