# c++ pure virtual function(abstract) used as callback for C library function

Tags: c++

I am creating a C++ library from a C library.
C library have functions that contain callback,and callback have also arg(number of arguments).

I want to expose callback class override functions to the user so that the user can access callback function data.
As shown in this [example user use callback class](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp/blob/master/src/samples/async_publish.cpp)

To simplify, I created the smallest version of my issue.
Here I am trying to use a standard C function with a callback and assign a pure virtual function as the callback.

```
/// library.h part of  code //////
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
    #include<stdio.h>
}

extern "C" {
    void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int (*)(const void *, const void *));   
}

struct callback{
    virtual int compare(const void *a, const void *b)=0;   
};

struct myclass{
    myclass()=default;
    callback *callback_;
    void mycallback(callback& cb){
        callback_ = &cb;
    }

    void sortdata(int *array,int size){
        qsort((void*)array,size,sizeof(int),callback::compare);
        //qsort((void*)array,size,sizeof(int),&callback_->compare);
    };
};
```

and

```
////Application.cpp part code ///////////////////
//#include "library.h"
class usercallback : public callback{
public:
    //currenty only one callback but in my case many
    virtual int compare(const void *a, const void *b) override{
        std::cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<std::endl;
        return *((int*)a) < *((int*)b);
    }
};

int main(){
    int array[] = {1,2,4,5,7,8,93,2,4,6,7,89,43,2,4,5};
    int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    myclass myobj;
    usercallback cb;   
    myobj.mycallback(cb);
    myobj.sortdata(array,size);
}
```

this program gives error and i gauss because of C++ internally pass this object as arg.

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘virtual int callback::compare(const void*, const void*)’
   23 |         qsort((void*)array,size,sizeof(int),callback::compare);
```

I have also read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480582/implementing-callback-for-c-library-as-pure-virtual-in-c-abstract-class).but it not solve my problem.

i also know that it can be solved by using **static**, but i want to expose a class to the users, [as in this example](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp/blob/master/src/samples/async_publish.cpp).
code building on Ubuntu.

Comment: C callbacks only allow to call static class member functions. The best you can have is a `void* context` parameter you can pass a `this` pointer, when registering a specific class instance with the cb interface.

Comment: Callbacks absolutely need to be static functions, because they're not called on an object.

Comment: `/// library.h part of  code //////
#include <iostream> extern "C" { #include<stdio.h> }` Wait, what? `iostream` shouldn't be included in a C style header and the `extern "C"` will also prevent the compilation of with a C compiler. Also never wrap includes like this.

Comment: This just might be a little bit too minimal. Show your *real* callback signature. It is a well established fact that people who invented `qsort` interface didn't really know what they were doing. Not from the modern software engineering perspective at any rate. It is not a representative example of a well-designed function accepting a callback.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution is to not paint yourself in that corner in the first place. If you have any leeway at all towards addressing this differently from a design standpoint, that should be your goto.

That being said, if you are stuck, and HAVE to make that interoperability work, you'll have to marhsall the `this` available from a free-floating function, which means a global variable. A private static member variable is the best approach for this here, and ideally, it should be `thread_local` for safety.

For example:

```
// library.h
struct myclass{
    myclass()=default;
    
    void mycallback(callback& cb){
        callback_ = &cb;
    }

    void sortdata(int *array,int size){
        active_instance_ = this;
        qsort((void*)array,size,sizeof(int),compare_entry);
        active_instance_ = nullptr;
    };

private:

    callback *callback_;
    static thread_local myclass* active_instance_;
    
    static int compare_entry(const void *a, const void *b) {
        assert(active_instance_);
        active_instance_->callback_->compare(a, b);
    }

};

// library.cpp
thread_local myclass* myclass::active_instance_ = nullptr;
```

Obviously, this is only fine for callbacks that only live until the stack unwinds. It is inappropriate for anything involving long-lived callbacks.

For those, hopefully, the API in question provides a `void* user_data` pointer in which you can store `this`. If so, then you would be able to do:

```
//assuming
void register_callback(void* user_data, void (*cb)(void*, int));

// library.h
struct myclass{
    myclass()=default;
    
    void mycallback(callback& cb){
        callback_ = &cb;
        register_callback(this, callback_entry);
    }

private:
    callback *callback_;
    static int callback_entry(void* user_data, int p) {
        auto self = reinterpret_cast<myclass*>(user_data);
        self->callback_->some_method(p);
    }
};
```

Comment: Global variables are not a good idea. It is much, much better to scrap this design and pass what is meant to be passed, a normal plain jane non-member function with no hidden anything.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. In general yes, but sometimes people are painted in a corner and have no choice. It's still worth answering the question as asked IMO, if only for the sake of completeness. A global variable is, AFAIK, unfortunately the only way to pull this off. I will however add a preamble mentioning that it's a last recourse. Thanks for the prompt.

Comment: Gcc has an extension for this: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Bound-member-functions.html

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow  I tried to work theat link you shared. It just remove error and build, but my objective to expose the callback class so user can **overload callback class pure virual function**,using this method I can't able to achieve my goal . As in [example link](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp/blob/master/src/samples/async_publish.cpp)  look how in main function use **class callback : public virtual mqtt::callback**

Comment: You are trying to make something work that isn't supposed to work like that. So I'm not surprised it's hard.